# delete function doesn't work in c# (with postgreSQL)

Tags: c#, postgresql, datagridview

I'm trying to modify my postgreSQL database via datagridview in windows forms.
I select a table name from my listbox, which displays the table contents in a datagridview, convert the table name to a string and use a switch to assign a deletion function to the selected table. My delete function doesn't work at all: pressing the button I've assigned to delete a selected row does nothing. My insert function for adding new data works just fine though.

Here's the code.

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selected = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        switch (selected)
        {
            case "gamemode":
                NpgsqlCommand delmode = new NpgsqlCommand("DELETE FROM gamemode WHERE id_gamemode=@id_gamemode", ncon);
                delmode.Parameters.Add("@id_gamemode", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, 255, "id_gamemode");
                remove.DeleteCommand = delmode;
                break;
        }
        remove.Update((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource);
    }
```

Comment: First question: where does `remove` come from?

Comment: It's a NpgsqlDataAdapter defined outside of the button2_click event

Comment: Is `button2_Click` the button you've "assigned to delete a selected row.."? I don't see it deleting anything. If your grid is properly bound, and you delete a row, the underlying `DataRowState` should be `Deleted` and it should work.

Comment: Yeah that's what the button should do. What have I done wrong?

Comment: A DbDataAdapter deletes, inserts or updates rows if they have their RowState property set to something different than DataRowState.Unchanged. You first need to find the row to delete in your datasource and call Delete on that row. Then you can call the Update command to have your change persisted in the database.

Comment: You haven't deleted a row from the grid. You may want to stick with convention and handle the [UserDeletingRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.userdeletingrow(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) event when the user selects a row and presses the delete key.

Comment: I didn't know i'm supposed to press the delete key and then press the button to save the change. I feel really embarrased. Thanks for the help though, Crowcoder and everyone else.